# Scroll buttons not showing on select element with custom css

Tags: css

I've styled the scrollbars in my web app with the following CSS.  I've specifically styled it to show the buttons at the top and bottom of the scrollbar.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
  display: block;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment{
 border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement{
 border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment{
 border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement{
 border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Works great on regular pages and scrollable divs, as you can see (when you run the code snippet) the scrollbar is styled and the buttons appear at the top and bottom of the bar. On select elements on the other hand, the top and bottom buttons do not appear.  Is it possible to show the buttons in a select?  If so, how?

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
  display: block;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment{
 border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement{
 border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment{
 border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement{
 border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
<option>Why no scroll buttons?</option>
</select>
```